# Unable to import pyPyrTools in python3

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing

I have installed pyPyrTools from [here](https://github.com/LabForComputationalVision/pyPyrTools) using:
`pip install pyPyrTools`

It showed a success but when importing this package, gives me an error as:
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stdin", line 1, in "module"
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyPyrTools'**

How do I use this Package?
Whats wrong?

Comment: If you are using a `venv`(pycharm for example), you also need to add that module to your project even if it is installed in your system --> In `File, settings, project interpreter` , similiar to other IDEs.

Comment: I'm not using a venv

Comment: can you provide a code sample?

Answer (score 0):

The way to debug such issues is first to determine which `python` and which `pip` you are using. Then, secondly, see where you installed the module and where Python is looking to find the mismatch.

So, if you use the command `python` to start Python, you would run this:

```
type python
```

If you use the command `python3`  to start Python, you would run this:

```
type python3
```

Now run the same command for `pip` or `pip3` according to which you use:

```
type pip       # or "type pip3"
```

Now see what versions of `python` and `pip` you are running:

```
python -V      # or "python3 -V" if you use "python3"
pip -V         # or "pip3 -V" if you use "pip3"
```

You should now know which versions of the tools you are using.

---

Now see where `pip` (or `pip3` if you use that) installed your `pyPyrTools`:

```
pip show pyPyrTools       # or "pip3 show pyPyrTools" if you use "pip3"
```

**Sample Output**

```
Name: pyPyrTools
Version: 0.2.3
Summary: Python tools for multi-scale image processing, including Laplacian pyramids, Wavelets, and Steerable Pyramids
Home-page: https://github.com/LabForComputationalVision/pyPyrTools
Author: Eero Simoncelli, Rob Young, and William F. Broderick
Author-email: eero.simoncelli@nyu.edu
License: MIT
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: Pillow, numpy, matplotlib, scipy
Required-by:
```

Especially important is the `Location:` field on 3rd last line.

---

Now check where your Python is actually looking for modules:

```
python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"     # or "python -c ..." if you use "python" rather than "python3"
```

**Sample Output**

```
['', '/Users/mark/StackOverflow', '/Users/mark/OpenCV/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/Users/mark/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

So, the `Location:` from the previous part of my answer **must** be listed here for Python to find `pyPyrTools`. If it isn't, you either installed using a `pip` that didn't match your `python`, or you didn't configure your PYTHONPATH correctly.

If you run the above commands, please click `edit` under your question and paste the output in there - NOT in a comment where it is hard to format and read.